# TCP data sending from python to logstash fails

Tags: python, tcp, logstash

I am trying to send data from python script over TCP and receive the same in the logstash.
But there is no exchange of data happening.

**logstash.conf**

```
input {
  tcp {
      port => 5959
      codec => json
  } 
}

filter{

}

output {
    stdout {codec => rubydebug}
}
```

**python :**

```
import json
import socket
import sys

HOST = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 5959

try:
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
except socket.error, msg:
    sys.stderr.write("[ERROR] %s\n" % msg[1])
    sys.exit(1)

try:
    sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error, msg:
    sys.stderr.write("[ERROR] %s\n" % msg[1])
    sys.exit(2)

msg = {'@message': 'python test message', '@tags': ['python', 'test']}

sock.sendall(json.dumps(msg))
sock.send('\n')
sock.close()
sys.exit(0)
```

After executing both the scripts I am neither getting any error nor data in the logstash so can someone help like what can be causing the issue.

Comment: No error description, read [ask]. Python 2 is old, why not start with Python 3? Also, if you want people to read your code, indent it consistently, it also helps you to find errors.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt  - thanks for the feedback. 1). There is no error. It is just that it is not working. 2). It's just a POC use case so using Python 2. 3). Edited and fixed indent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just added `sock.send('\n')` after `sock.sendall(json.dumps(msg))` and it worked. It seems that there is an open issue with **logstash-codec-json** as[1](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/tcp-data-sending-from-pyton-to-logstash-fails/130358) :

> The logstash 'json' plugin still requires a newline '\n' to terminate json logs being sent over a TCP input.[2](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-codec-json/issues/15)

References :

1. [TCP data sending from pyton to logstash fails.](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/tcp-data-sending-from-pyton-to-logstash-fails/130358)
2. [The logstash 'json' codec still requires a newline '\n' as a delimiter to terminate json logs being sent over a TCP input.](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-codec-json/issues/15)